# Derivative of the definite integral

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have to find the derivative for

$$\int_{-1}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt-\int_{3}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt$$

When I calculate their derivative separately

$$\frac {d}{dt} \left(\int_{-1}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt\right)-\frac {d}{dt}\left(\int_{3}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt\right)$$

it gives me the right result, that is $0$.

But according to the law of additive

\begin{aligned}
&\int_{-1}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt-\int_{3}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt \\
= & \int_{-1}^x \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt+\int_{x}^3 \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt \\= &\int_{-1}^3 \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt \\[2em]
\end{aligned}

$$d/dt\int_{-1}^3 \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt = \frac{3^2}{3^2+4} = \frac 9{13}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Your last formula is false: $\int_{-1}^3(t^2\bigm/(t^2+4))\, dt$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

You have to obtain the *derivative* $\frac d{dx}$ of $$\int_{-1}^3 \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt$$

so the result will be

$$\frac d{dx}\int_{-1}^3 \frac{t^2}{t^2+4}dt =\frac d{dx}(const.) = 0$$

Comment: The very first "=" is false (that 9/13 is what the OP thought that the *derivative* would equal, by “replacing $t$ with the upper bound 3”). But of course it's true that the derivative of an integral with constants bounds is zero.

Comment: @HansLundmark, you're right, of course. Thanks, I corrected my answer.